# How do I correctly use an ACES workflow with CinemaDNG footage in Davinci Resolve?

Tags: color-correction

I'm just now discovering ACES with Resolve version 11. I can get Sony S-Log2 footage to look good, but I'm having trouble with CinemaDNG from my 2.5kBMCC. I've seen [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7DqtW7LB7g) tutorial on how to do it, but when I get to the step where you select an IDT, CinemaDNG is not available. Any thoughts on why this might be so? Is there something different I have to do in version 11 than what this guy's doing in 9.x? Here's the IDTs from which I have to choose, in case I'm just crazy.  [image: available formats]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use BMD Film (Black Magic Design) This is the colorspace used by the Black Magic Cameras.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there isn't a means to create an IDT for cinemaDNG footage in resolve.

cinemaDNG is a container and contains camera RAW data so it's precisely the kind of footage one would want to convert to ACES.  The problem is the IDT needs to be built with knowledge of the specific camera.  Theoretically this camera characterization data is included in the DNG tags, but there isn't currently a means to convert those tags into a useable IDT.